# how/where do Xcode 6 launch screen sizes correspond to Apple docs?

Tags: iphone, xcode6

I am sure this info is somewhere but I can't find it, and the Apple Developer hotline seems to have no idea what I'm talking about. In the assets library for launch screen in Xcode, there are slots labeled:

iPhone Portrait ---> Retina HD 5.5 & Retina HD 4.7
iOS8

iPhone Portrait ---> 2x & Retina 4
iOS 7, 8

iPhone Portrait ---> 1x, 2x & Retina 4
iOS 5, 6

I had launch screens prepared and I have the sizes for these individual files, but I don't see how their sizes correspond to these Apple labels within Xcode. Moreover, the Apple docs here (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH26-SW1 which is what Apple Developer referred me to) just refer to iphone 6 and 6s sizes, which doesn't correspond to the Xcode label organization.

This seems like it should be a 1 minute query. What am I missing and where is this super basic information?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you select the image "slot" in the asset catalog and show the Attributes inspector (on the right-hand side), it will show (among other things) "Expected Size" for each image. Doing that, it looks like:

```
iPhone Portrait iOS8 Retina HD 5.5: 1242 x 2208
iPhone Portrait iOS8 Retina HD 4.7: 750 x 1334
```

In the Attributes inspector, you can also choose which "slots" you want included via a series of checkboxes.

[image]

Documentation-wise, see the [Icon and Image Sizes section of the iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27).

Paraphrasing from there:

```
iPhone 6 Plus: Use a Launch File
iPhone 6: Use a Launch File
iPhone 5: 640 x 1136
iPhone 4s: 640 x 960
iPad (@2x): 1536 x 2048 (portrait), 2048 x 1536 (landscape)
iPad (@1x): 768 x 1024 (portrait), 1024 x 768 (landscape)
```

Also see the [Launch Images section](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH22-SW1), which says:

> Although it’s best to use a launch file for iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus, you can
> instead supply static launch images if necessary. If you need to create static
> launch images for these devices, use the following sizes:
>
> For iPhone 6:
> 750 x 1334 (@2x) for portrait
> 1334 x 750 (@2x) for landscape
>
> For iPhone 6 Plus:
> 1242 x 2208 (@3x) for portrait
> 2208 x 1242 (@3x) for landscape

It's worth noting that if you're only supporting iOS 8, you can just use a launch XIB or Storyboard and you don't need to worry about particular images sizes. The [Launch Images](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH22-SW1) section has information on that.

My most recent app update (which is iOS 8 only) is using XIB files (one for iPhone, one for iPad) and it works great.

Comment: But where is the landscape launchimage for iPhone 4.7 inch?

Comment: iPhone 6 (and 6s, and 7) are 4.7". So, as it says above: 1334 x 750 landscape.

Answer (score 7):

```
Retina HD 5.5 - 1242x2208
Retina HD 4.7 - 750x1334
Retina HD 5.5 landscape - 2208x1242
2x - 640x960
Retina 4 - 640x1136
1x - 320x480
default 320x568
default@x2 640x1136
```